# How to Load a bunch of images Stored in server into android app

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments

We want to load images which are stored in PHP server into our android app.
We have stored image urls in mysql db and we are able to fetch them all in an ArrayList **imgNames** but we are not able to set them into the gridview .

We also have to maintain the **aspect ratio** of the image because its a painting image that we waant to show and we cannot show it in static square blocks .

This is our code in which we fetch the image urls from the server -- >

```
    public class fragmentShopall extends Fragment{


        public JSONObject jsonResponse;
        public JSONArray jsonMainNode;
        public ListView mListView;
        public ArrayList<String> mylist,imgNames ;
        public ArrayAdapter<String> dataAdapter;
        public GridView grid;
        public ListView list;
         public fragmentShopall(){}

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragmentshopall, container, false);
        grid=(GridView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.gridView1); 
        list = (ListView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.listView1);

        testAsynch MyTask= new testAsynch();
        MyTask.execute();

        return rootView;
    }

    class testAsynch extends AsyncTask<Void,Integer,String> 
    {
        String readFeed;
        JSONObject json;
        StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();

        protected void onPreExecute(){

                Log.d("PreExceute","On pre Exceute......");
        }

      protected String doInBackground(Void...arg0) {

        Log.d("DoINBackGround","On doInBackground...");
        StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
        HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();

        // domain intentionally obfuscated for security reasons
        //HttpGet httpGet = new HttpGet("http://innobytes.in/webservices/category");
        HttpGet httpGet = new HttpGet("http://10.0.2.2/pratik/category");
        httpGet.setHeader("content-type", "application/json; charset=UTF-8");
        try 
        {
        HttpResponse response = client.execute(httpGet);
        StatusLine statusLine = response.getStatusLine();
        int statusCode = statusLine.getStatusCode();
        if (statusCode == 200) {
            HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
            InputStream content = entity.getContent();
            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(content));
            String line;
            while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                builder.append(line);
              }
            } else {
                Log.d("onProgressUpdate","Failed to download file..........");
            }
        } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return builder.toString();

    }

        @SuppressWarnings("null")
        protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
                // NOTE: You can call UI Element here.
            String autcElement = null;
            String img;

    String url="http://innobytes.in/artsgallery.in/productpic/";
    imgNames = new ArrayList<String>();
    mylist = new ArrayList<String>();                       
        try{
            readFeed = result;

            JSONArray jsonarray = new JSONArray(readFeed);

            System.out.println("OKAY_8!!");
            //*********** Process each JSON Node ***********//*

            int lengthJsonArr = jsonarray.length();

        for (int i = 0; i < lengthJsonArr; i++) 
            {

            System.out.println("OKAY_9!!");
        //****** Get Object for each JSON node. ***********//*
            JSONObject jsonChildNode = jsonarray.getJSONObject(i);
            autcElement = jsonChildNode.optString("tbimageurl").toString();
            imgNames.add(autcElement);
            img=url+autcElement;
            mylist.add(img);
            System.out.println(""+img);

            System.out.print(" Hi....  "+mylist.get(i));

//Picasso.with(getActivity()).load("http://innobytes.in/artsgallery.in/productpic/"+autcElement).into((Target) list);

            }

        }                   
        catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

            // Close progress dialog
        }
      }
    }
```

What would be the best possible solution to get the images using the urls that we fetched and display them all while **maintaining their aspect ratio** maybe like Pinterest or Flickr  ?

Comment: set adapter from where are storing image url in database..wait I will give you example

Comment: Sure an example would be great .

Answer (score 0):

Instead of downloading each and every image you can use [`LazyList Loading`](https://www.google.co.in/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=2&ved=0CDIQFjAB&url=https://github.com/thest1/LazyList&ei=b8gVU6CNMoLrrQfdwIHIDg&usg=AFQjCNEtH-ZaRywtimgz2DGvuBVibs666w&sig2=YDd8gBRQ3WifgxiQhALK1Q&bvm=bv.62286460,d.bmk&cad=rja) mechanism

Basically lazy list loading is lazy loading of images from sd-card or from server using urls. It is like on demand loading images.

Images can be cached to local sd-card or phone memory. Url is considered the key. If the key is present in sd-card, display images from sd-card else display image by downloading from server and cache the same to location of your choice. The cache limit can set. You can also choose your own location to cache images. Cache can also be cleared.

Instead of user waiting to download large images and then displaying lazy list, loads images on demand. Since images are cached you can display images offline.

Answer (score 0):

firstly create bean for initializing your value's
like that

```
public class Beanclassname {

    private String mediaImageUrl;


    public String getMediaImageUrl() {
        return mediaImageUrl;
    }
    public void setMediaImageUrl(String mediaImageUrl) {
        this.mediaImageUrl = mediaImageUrl;
    }
}
```

now put values in bean and atlast add it in arraylist and do setadapter
like that

```
bean.setMediaImageUrl(jsonChildNode.getString("key"));
arraylist.add(bean);
_adapter = new adapter(this, arraylist);
                        gridview.setAdapter(_adapter);
                        _adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
```

now in your adapter use lazy imageloader to display image

Comment: in adapter class initialize imageloader like that ImageLoader imageLoader=null;  imageLoader=new ImageLoader(activity); and then call display method of image loader imageLoader.DisplayImage(bean.getMediaImageUrl(), R.drawable.ic_stub, view.imgView);

Comment: Can you mail a short sample demo (vishaln101@gmail.com) Plzzzz !!! I am newbie in this so getting a little confused ..

Comment: fine now we have removed the fragment and v are using normal acitivity .. will try and get back to you .. Thanks for the help !!

Answer (score 0):

You can also use Android Image Loader library.

Check this - https://github.com/nostra13/Android-Universal-Image-Loader

Advantages of using this library -

1. Multithread image loading
2. Image caching in memory and/or on device's file system (or SD card)